# How can I further divide subgroup to conduct simple effect analysis in meta-analysis?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, metafor

I am meta-analyzing in R using *metafor*. I learned how to conduct subgroup analysis and plot the results [from the website](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/plots:forest_plot_with_subgroups#code) like this:

```
### fit random-effects model in the three subgroups
res.s <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure="RR",
             subset=(alloc=="systematic"), method="REML")
res.r <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure="RR",
             subset=(alloc=="random"), method="REML")
res.a <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure="RR",
             subset=(alloc=="alternate"), method="REML")

### add summary polygons for the three subgroups
addpoly(res.s, row=18.5, cex=0.75, atransf=exp, mlab="")
addpoly(res.r, row= 7.5, cex=0.75, atransf=exp, mlab="")
addpoly(res.a, row= 1.5, cex=0.75, atransf=exp, mlab="")
```

My question is, can I further divide those three subgroups? For example, dividing with year as well as allocation: 
70s systematic, 70s random, 70s alternate; 
80s systematic, 80s random, 80s alternate; 
90s systematic, 90s random, 90s alternate.

And, I hope this is the way to deal with interactions in meta-regression.